# Eclipse plugin development: How to inform view that content has changed?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm developing my first Eclipse plugin. For that I used an example that has a simple view. I added a IStructuredContentProvider to provide the view with content. The first time when it is loaded it works, but when I changed the content, the view isn't updated. What should I do?

This is my IStructuredContentProvider:

```
public class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {

    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();

    private void addProject(Project project) {
        if (!projects.contains(project)) {
            projects.add(project);
        }
    }

    public void addProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        for (Project project : projects) {
            addProject(project);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
        return projects.toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the description of `inputChanged()` method:

> A typical use for this method is registering the content provider as a listener to changes on the new input (using model-specific means), and deregistering the viewer from the old input. In response to these change notifications, the content provider should update the viewer (**see the add, remove, update and refresh methods on the viewers**).

Comment: Yes I found that too, but when i do a sysout in this method, it is not called when i add new items to the content provider.

Comment: @Roflcoptr inputChanged() is called when you call viewer.setInput(). This is your chance to get a reference to the viewer, so that when you later change something in your content you can call e.g. viewer.refresh() from the provider.